# Automatic SMS Verification with Authy

Tags: twilio, authy

I developped a mobile app using our backend to register and verify users using Authy.
This is done by the backend in 3 steps:

1/ The app requests the backend to register the user. 
The backend calls https://api.authy.com/protected/json/users/new (email, cellphone, countrycode). It provides back the userId later used.

2/ The app requests the backend to send a sms code the user.
The backend calls https://api.authy.com/protected/json/sms/{1}?locale={2}{3}" (userId, language, force)

3/ The user now receives the SMS. He fills it in the mobile app, which eventually is sent to the backend for verification.
The backend calls https://api.authy.com/protected/json/verify/{1}/{2}{3}" (token, userId, force)

I wanted to use Automatic SMS Verification with the SMS Retriever API in my mobile app (https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview) to avoid the hassle for the user to enter his verification code.
It requres to set up a hash in the verification code, but unfortunately I don't seem to have any control on what Authy generates.

Am I missing something here to get it work?

Rgds

R.

Comment: Hey, I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio/Authy. Can you drop me an email about this at philnash@twilio.com. We might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

No, you just can't affect the text in Authy's SMS. So, for now, it looks like we can't support retriever API.